# why strace ignores my alias for rm?

Tags: alias, strace

I have an `alias` set for my `rm` command. If I run `alias` command, this is what I get as output.

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

Now, when I run the `rm` command it works fine as expected.

```
rm ramesh
rm: remove regular empty file `ramesh'? y
```

Now, I was learning on the system calls that are being called when I execute a command. For that I got to know about the `strace` command from [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/9031/list-files-accessed-by-a-command) which lists me the files that are being called when I execute some command. The command is as below.

```
strace -ff -e trace=file rm ramesh 2>&1
```

The command works perfectly fine except that it ignores my aliases that I have in place for my `rm` command. It deletes the file without prompting the user.

So, does `strace` ignore aliases like this? If so why is it so?

**EDIT:**

Not sure, if this has something to do but `type -a rm` gives me the output as,

```
rm is aliased to `rm -i'
rm is /bin/rm
```

So is it considering `/bin/rm` in this case which is why the user is not prompted before deletion?

Comment: `strace` does not ignore aliases, because that would imply there was something to ignore in the first place. An alias is a feature of the shell. `strace` is a different program, and inside `strace` the concept of aliases does not exist, hence there is nothing to ignore. The API provided by the kernel for executing programs does not have a concept of aliases either, so there is no way the shell could tell strace about aliases, even if it wanted to.

Comment: If you want to `strace` an alias, you have to `strace` the shell, which implements the alias. There is a few approaches you could take to doing that: `strace -p $$ &` or `strace bash` or `strace sh -c 'rm ramesh'` (the last will also ignore the alias, but for an entirely different reason.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`strace` doesn't run `rm -i` for the same reason as:

```
echo rm
```

doesn't output `rm -i`.

Aliases are a feature of a few shells to allow some strings to automatically be replaced by another when found in command position.

In:

```
alias foo='whatever'
foo xxx
```

The shells expands that to:

```
whatever xxx
```

and that undergoes another round of interpretation, in that case leading to executing the `whatever` command.

aliases are only expanded when found in command position (as the first word of a command line).

`zsh` supports *global* aliases.

You could do:

```
alias -g rm='rm -i'
```

But you wouldn't want to, as that would mean that:

```
echo rm
```

would output `rm -i` for instance.

Answer (score 9):

`strace` uses the `PATH` environment variable to locate the program to be traced, rather than executing it through the shell (which would clutter up the output).  A shell alias isn't a program, it's a feature of the shell, and so `strace` ignores it.

Running `strace strace rm` is rather enlightening, as well as being interestingly recursive.

Answer (score 5):

An alias is a feature of your shell. However, strace executes the command directly (using `execve`, probably), which does not involve the shell. (If strace executed the given command through the shell, then the output of strace would contain all of the shell execution syscalls rather than just those from the process of interest.)

Furthermore, when you run `strace rm ramesh`, the interactive shell does not attempt to substitute your alias in the arguments to strace, because that would be terribly confusing for everybody. The shell only expands aliases that appear in the first position on a command line.

Answer (score 2):

strace uses `execve c function` such as `find command`,However `find uses exec function` You can't use `aliases`, `built-in shell command` or so on.

You have to do:

```
strace /bin/rm -i ramesh
```

Answer (score 2):

To build on Stéphane Chazelas’s answer, if you define

```
alias strace="strace "
```

(with a space at the end) then the command

```
strace rm ramesh
```

*will* be processed as

```
strace rm -i ramesh
```

But even this will work for only the first word after the `strace`,
so it wouldn’t apply directly to your example (where you have intervening options). 
*But,* if you define

```
alias my_strace="strace -ff -e trace=file "
```

then

```
my_strace rm ramesh
```

*will* be processed as

```
strace -ff -e trace=file rm -i ramesh
```

Answer (score 2):

### No aliases here

Let's assume we have the alias definition `alias rm='rm -i'` in our `~/.bashrc`. The alias adds the option for prompting before removing each file:

```
$ touch ./file
$ rm ./file
/bin/rm: remove regular empty file ‘./file’?
```

It's not the fault of `strace` that it did not use the alias:
It has just nothing to do with aliases.

In the command

```
$ strace -f -e file -o rm.strace rm ./file
```

The words `rm` and `./file` are just arguments for strace for now - the shell can not expand the alias `rm`, because it can not know that strace will use these arguments as command later.

In general, command aliases can only be used where commands can be.

Aliases are a feature of the shell, and `strace` does not use a shell at all when it calls the command from the command line. It uses `exec()` instead, with the commands and arguments from it's own command line.

Inside of `strace`, the command will be called with something similar to `exec("rm", "file")`, and `exec()` will find `/bin/rm` in PATH - without using a shell.

### Explicit shell

Now, why not include a shell in the `strace` command?

```
$ touch ./file
$ strace -f -e file -o rm.strace bash -c 'rm ./file'
$ ls ./file
ls: cannot access ./file: No such file or directory
```

Hmm... that did not work. `rm` just deleted the file, without the `-i` prompt.

### Interactive aliases

Aliases are normally only enabled in interactive shells, actual command lines in a terminal.
With our example alias, it's easy to see why that makes sense: If the `rm -i` alias would be expanded inside shell scripts, they would hang at the first `rm` with nobody there for pressing `y`.

Aliases are controlled by the shell option `expand_aliases`. We could set the option with `bash +O expand_aliases -c ...`. But that's not enough, because the non-interactive shell will also not read `~/.bashrc`. That means, our alias is not only switched off by the option, but also not even defined.

### Pretending to be interactive

The easy way to handle both parts is to use the command line option `-i` to make the shell pretend it is interactive:

```
$ touch ./file
$ strace -f -e file -o rm.strace bash -i -c 'rm ./file'
/bin/rm: remove regular empty file ‘./file’?
```

Finally, the `-i` alias was used!

Note that you would not normally use shells running with the `-i` option for scripting, even if you would want to have your aliases available, for example.